# What is a good term for a fake laugh or a laugh used to camouflage a snide remark?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm composing a message to a passive aggressive friend who is quite phoney - they constantly make nasty remarks with a fake laugh attached so as not to be blatantly obvious about their intentions. I would like some feedback on a good word used for that laugh. I could look in the thesaurus or urban dictionary but I prefer hearing other opinions.

I don't need advice on the relationship or test if the message just the word associated with the laugh.

Comment: Welcome, gabrielle. Doing research, such as looking in dictionaries and thesauruses, is a prerequisite for asking questions here on ELU; see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center for more information. Also, please note that single-word-requests require an example sentence showing how you want to use the requested word to enable answerers to make more relevant suggestions.

Comment: It is honest of you to admit you would rather have us do the research.

Answer (score 3):

Often such a laugh is called a **snicker** or a **snigger**.

- **[Snicker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snicker)**

> to laugh in a covert or partly suppressed manner

A recent example from the news media:

> The most common responses were to **snicker** about the lack of real photographic or video evidence and to tag a friend and jokingly ask what they were doing in the woods that night.

- "North Carolina Man Claims Face-to-Face Encounter With Big Hair Biped." *[The Epoch Times](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/2278326-north-carolina-man-claims-face-to-face-encounter-with-big-hair-biped/)*, August 8, 2017